# Error al iterar sobre arreglo con ngFor

Tags: angular, angular6, ngfor

Intento iterar un arreglo utilizando lo siguiente `*ngFor="let item of items"`, sabiendo que ngFor se utiliza para iterar sobre arreglos de varias matrices, si hago una consulta por que me devuelva por ejemplo: las materias que tiene inscritas un alumno, sabiendo que el alumno puede tener inscritas 1 o muchas carreras.

En el caso de que tenga inscritas mas de 1 materia no hay problema en utilizar ngFor, pero si el alumno tiene inscrita 1 sola carreras, que es el caso que me esta sucediendo, ngFor genera un error que dice que solo puede iterar sobre arreglos de varias matrices.

Como podría solucionar este problema, ya que esta consulta como he dicho me devuelve en formato json mi arreglo pero puede contener 1 o varios elementos.

De que manera puedo utilizar el ngFor para iterar sobre el arreglo asi traiga 1 o varios elementos?

Si mi arreglo viene así el ngFor funciona:

```
[
 {
 "userId": 1,
 "title": "medicina",
 "status": 1
 },
 {
 "userId": 1,
 "title": "informatica",
 "status": 1
 }
]
```

Pero si viene así el ngFor no funciona:

```
[
 {
 "userId": 1,
 "title": "informatica",
 "status": 1
 }
]
```

Y el error que muestra es el siguiente:

```
error trying to diff. only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Muestro el arreglo en console y es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este arreglo es cuando un estudiante tiene una sola carrera inscrita

El metodo que trae los datos y los mete en items en mi archivo .ts es el siguiente

```
 public items:any=[];

 datosAcademicosUser() {
  let data:Observable<any>;
  data = this.http.getData(this.userDetails.id,"get/datauser");
  data.subscribe( result => {
   this.items = result;
  }, (err) => {
   console.log(err);
  });
 }
```

El codigo html es el siguiente

```
<ion-card-content *ngFor="let item of items">
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-12>
        <button ion-button full block small round color="dark">{{item.NombCar}}</button>
      </ion-col>
     </ion-row>
   </ion-grid>
   <p *ngIf="item.status==1; else inactivo" style="color:crimson;font-weight: bold;text-align: center">
     Tienes inscripción activa
   </p>
   <ng-template #inactivo>
    <p style="color:crimson;font-weight: bold;text-align: center">Inactivo</p>
   </ng-template>
</ion-card-content>
```

El arreglo en formato json es el siguiente:

```
[
 {
  "id_inscripcion":"1",
  "0":"1",
  "estudiante_id":"1",
  "1":"1",
  "carrera_id":"192",
  "2":"192",
  "indice":"3.90",
  "3":"3.90",
  "status":"1",
  "4":"1",
  "turno":"Diurno",
  "5":"Diurno",
  "sede":"1",
  "6":"1",
  "condicion":"RG",
  "7":"RG",
  "uc_aprobadas":"150",
  "8":"150",
  "CodCar":"192",
  "9":"192",
  "NombCar":"INGENIERIA INFORMATICA",
  "10":"INGENIERIA INFORMATICA",
  "codVice":"1",
  "11":"1",
  "ciudad":"Barinas",
  "12":"Barinas"
 }
]
```

Estoy utilizando angular 6

Comment: Alejo, estas haciendolo en angularjs(1) o en angular (2+)? Pon el código de ejemplo, por favor. En angular1 sería ng-repeat, no *ngFor

Comment: Estás seguro de que cuando tienes un único valor es un array? ngFor funciona perfectamente incluso con 0 valores (no mostrando nada) o 1 valor (se produce una iteración)

Comment: por favor crea un [mcve], así podemos descartar que haya algún problema relacionado

Comment: Hola Alejo. El primer JSON está mal formado (falta una coma entre ambos valores de la matriz). ¿Podrías compartir tanto el HTML que usa el `ngFor` y el código javascript que asigna el valor de `items`.

Comment: Oscar he editado la pregunta agregando el codigo que estoy utilizando.

Comment: Hola @AlejoMendoza deberías de agregar tu código html para ver la iteración del arreglo declarado y si puedes, deberías pintar en consola el arreglo que tengas declarado para verificar si hasta esa parte lo trae de forma correcta

Comment: @jecorrales he editado y colocado la informacion completa en mi pregunta

Comment: Ok, puedes poner todo el arreglo que tienes en formato JSON? por encima creo que tu problema radica allí, `personas: any[] = [
    {
      'nombre_persona': 'Felipe',
      'apellido_persona':'Fernandes',
      'nombre_producto':'Computador',
      'cantidad_producto':'5',
      'costo_producto':'25000',
    }
  ];`esto a manera de ejemplo del como deberia declararse

Comment: @jecorrales he colocado el arreglo que me trae el servidor en formato json

Comment: He intentado reproducir tu error en Angular y no me arroja error alguno, voy a seguir mirando y te cuento.

Comment: @jecorrales corregi la respuesta del servidor y he tomado el consejo de la respuesta de ivan.depi. Funcionando como debe ser.! Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ngFor** solo funciona con arrays y no con objetos.

```
var objetoNombre = []; // Intentar recorrer este objeto con ngFor produce un error
var arrayNombres = {}: // Esto es un array
```